# Proving the generalization of Euler's formula for a graph $G$ with $k$ connected components: $V(G)-E(G)+F(G) = k+1$

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

Let $G$ be a planar graph.

Let $V(G)$ denote its numbers of vertices, $E(G)$ its number of edges and $F(G)$ its number of faces.

Show that if $G$ has $k$ connected components, then $$V(G)-E(G)+F(G) = k+1$$
which generalizes Euler's formula for a connected planar graph: $V(G)-E(G)+F(G) = 2$

---

**Proof by induction in k**

*Initial step ($k=1$)*:

This follows directly from Eulers formula.

*Induction step*:

Suppose the above claim is true for $k$ connected components. We want to show this implies it's true for $k+1$ connected components as well.

Let $\tilde{G}$ be a planar graph with $k+1$ connected components. Consider the following division of $\tilde{G}$ into a graph $\tilde{G_k}$ that has $k$ connected components and $\tilde{G_1}$ that is itself connected.

By the induction assumption $V(\tilde{G_k})-E(\tilde{G_k})+F(\tilde{G_k}) = k+1$ and by the initial step $V(\tilde{G_1})-E(\tilde{G_1})+F(\tilde{G_1}) = 2$.

Note that $\tilde{G_k}$ and $\tilde{G_1 }$ share excactly 1 face so we have

$$V(\tilde{G})-E(\tilde{G})+F(\tilde{G})= (V(\tilde{G_k})+V(\tilde{G_1}))-(E(\tilde{G_k})+E(\tilde{G_1}))+(F(\tilde{G_k})+F(\tilde{G_1})-1)$$

$$=V(\tilde{G_k})-E(\tilde{G_k})+F(\tilde{G_k})+V(\tilde{G_1})-E(\tilde{G_1})+F(\tilde{G_1})-1=k+1+2-1=k+2$$

which proves the desired result.

$\blacksquare$

**My question is:** Is my proof good/valid? Should I be more precise why they share a face? And if so, how can I do that?

Comment: The proof looks good, but you have to stipulate that we can have an always come up with an embedding such that $\tilde G_k$ and $\tilde G_1$ share exactly 1 face, so to avoid embeddings like these: Take as $\tilde G$ the graph with a simple loop and two additional edges, one in the loop, one outside, so that it has $2+1$ connected components. Take $\tilde G_1$ to be the loop, and $\tilde G_2$ to be the two additional edges. Then $\tilde G_2$ has $2$ connected components, but $\tilde G_2$ and $\tilde G_1$ share 2 faces.

Comment: Ah I see this can happen. Hmmm I'm not quite sure how to construct this. Can you give a hint to an embedding?